# svn commit messages

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a svn which I access by Tortoise svn.

I would like to get all my messages (1000+) from my 'commits', is this possible without using the repobrowser and copy/paste all of then one by one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using TortoiseSVN you can open repo browser, right click on repo root directory -> *Show log* -> *Show all* to get all log messages listed in the window. Then select all entries in list, right click -> *Copy to clipboard*.

You get the full log history in plain text format. Not sure whether it's the same format you get by using the command line client, but looks close.

Comment: Sorry I'm an idiot when it comes to IDE stuff sometimes, I remember to keep it simple sidney in the future. +1 & accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use the command line client and the [`svn log` command](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html).

Comment: No it uses the librries and does not install the SVN commandline client

Comment: If the command line tools aren't installed by default with TortoiseSVN, then you can always install them separately.

Comment: Adding `--xml` makes it easier to parse the output of `svn log`.